# Necessity of demean/detrend before low/high pass filter

Tags: python, lowpass-filter, butterworth

I am curious about the necessity of demean/detrend before low/high pass filter.

I have seismic data which had been processed by cross correlation or other things.
I want to use low pass filter for the processed data.
For the raw seismic data, I know demean/detrend are needed before low-pass filter.
But for the processed data which were going through demean/detrend during processing, is it still necessary to apply demean/detrend?

Comment: I'm not sure this is really on-topic for SO. It might be better suited for the [Earth Science StackExchange](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/).